# Grouping data under custom category in the timer profiler section

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I've been added to the timer profiler section customs data, but it seems that i'm having problem grouping it.

My code looks like :

```
if (null !== $this->stopwatch) {
    $e = $this->stopwatch->start($name.'.ws', 'webservice');
}

$soap->myWebServiceCall();

if (null !== $this->stopwatch) {
    $e->stop();
}
```

`stopwatch` refers to the service with the `id` `debug.stopwatch`

As you can see on the screenshow below, it fails grouping the result within a "Webservice" category. (It currtently store them under "default" section).

What's wrong ? Thanks.

[image: timer profiler]